# toggle dataset ternary with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, dataset

Anyone knows how to toggle data-attr with elvis operator? My function works:

```
function toogleActive(el) {
    if (el.dataset.active == "false") {
        el.dataset.active = "true";
    } else {
        el.dataset.active = "false";
    }
}
```

but I want make it more laconic, something like this:

```
el.dataset.active = "false" ? "true" : "false";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
function toogleActive(el) {
    el.dataset.active = (el.dataset.active === "true") ? "false" : "true";
}
```